# Inverse of that $X$ is a variety $\Rightarrow \mathbb{V}(\mathbb{I}(X)) = X$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We know that if $X$ is an affine variety, then we have $ \mathbb{V}(\mathbb{I}(X)) = X$. My question is, what about the inverse? If I know $ \mathbb{V}(\mathbb{I}(X)) = X$, can we conclude that $X$ is an affine variety?

Comment: Does your definition of variety require irreducibility? If yes, then no, because this will also be true for finite unions of varieties. Otherwise, yes, because everything of the form $\mathbb{V}(I)$ for some ideal $I$ is a variety.

Comment: @MattPressland, not require irreducibility .and seems you are right!..

Comment: In that case, I shall make it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, everything of the form $\mathbb{V}(I)$ for some ideal $I$ is an affine variety. As $\mathbb{I}(X)$ is an ideal, $\mathbb{V}(\mathbb{I}(X))$ is a variety, so if $X=\mathbb{V}(\mathbb{I}(X))$ then $X$ is a variety.